# How to convert an object to a list in netbeans?

Tags: android, netbeans

here is my code, the sql query returns objects, but the return method returns a list, i can't fix it.

```
@GET
@Path("returnPlaceName/{studentid}")
@Produces({"application/json"})
public List<Location> returnPlaceName(@PathParam("studentid") Integer studentid) {
    TypedQuery<Location> q = em.createQuery("SELECT l.locationname, count(l.locationname) FROM Location l where l.studentid.studentid = :studentid GROUP BY l.locationname", Location.class);
    q.setParameter("studentid", studentid);
    return q.getResultList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand all, but your query return ever list for condition:

```
SELECT l.locationname, count(l.locationname) FROM Location l where l.studentid.studentid = :studentid GROUP BY l.locationname
```

If you want only 1 record, take:

```
SELECT l.locationname, count(l.locationname) FROM Location l where l.studentid.studentid = :studentid AND l.locationname = :locationname
```

And if you want get who first option, you need use foreach, example:

```
for(Location loc : yourList){
.
.
.
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: it requires to 'return a list of place names and their frequency. Returning a Map type object is what come to my mind as the place name and frequency stand for key and value respectively. But the query returns objects, i can't convert it to list to get correct result.